# c# wpf devexpress grid control how to get object of parent row

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress, gridcontrol

I have a grid control data table within cell template combobox. i'm listening for selectionChanged event from it (using mvvm), and can't get a GridRow parent from a child (with VisualTreeHelper.GetParent((ComboBox)EventArgs.Source)).

Can you help me to get a binded object of parent row?

It has some information to update data base (guid and new value, changed with combobox). 
in default wpf DataGrid it looks like:

```
DataGridRow dgr = DataGridRow.GetRowContainingElement((ComboBox)sender);
var v = ((MyItem)dgr.DataContext).Guid;
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i got this by CellValueChangedEventArgs.Row property